# Is there a method to determine if all collections in a firebase database are empty?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to know if their is a built in method to check if all collections in a firebase database are empty.

I could write a method checking each collection individually and then wrap it in a function, but I first want to check if a built-in method is available for this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in method for this.  If you want to know if any collection is empty, you have to query it by name, and see that it returns 0 documents.